# Porque detecta class que se borran

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy intentando hacer un script en jquery que detecte un class dentro de otro y cuando lo detecte notifique, lo borre y siga ejecutando hasta que detecte otro.

Pero el problema es que detecta un class que se borra antes y no esta en el DOM.

https://jsfiddle.net/j7swht8q/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var audio = new Audio('https://www.myinstants.com/media/sounds/sound-9______.mp3');
var $myDiv = $('.foo .biz');
var divss = 0;
function detect_drop(){
    if ( $myDiv.length) {
       divss++;
        console.log(divss);  
        audio.play();
        $( $myDiv ).remove();
        
    }
}
setInterval(detect_drop, 10000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar">
<div class="biz"></div>
  </div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Nadie sabe contestarme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque el div ya no está en el DOM, la variable $myDiv no ha cambiado y sigue conteniendo los elementos que había en su momento.

Una opción sería calcular $myDiv en cada ejecución así:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var audio = new Audio('https://www.myinstants.com/media/sounds/sound-9______.mp3');
  var divss = 0;
  function detect_drop(){
    var $myDiv = $('.foo .biz');
    if ( $myDiv.length) {
          divss++;
          console.log(divss);  
          audio.play();
          $( $myDiv ).remove();   
      }
  }
  setInterval(detect_drop, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfectamente